# copying and pasting url from clipboard on my android

Tags: wireless, android

For the last couple of days I have been trying to figure out how to copy a YouTube URL from the clipboard and paste it into VLC on my Android to no avail.

If someone knows how to walk me through this task, it would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: it might help if you describe which clipboard you are talking about. Are you copying URL's from the Android or another device? Is the youtube hosted on the Android or another device?

Answer (score -1):

[PUSHBULLET](https://www.pushbullet.com/) is a wonderful tool that lets you share links, files, and other things to all your devices from your computer.

See also [THIS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android&hl=en) link for Android.